# Nokia HERE Maps javascript API: How to add an offset to map.zoomTo(boundingBox)?

Tags: javascript, here-api

currently we are using **HERE Javascript Api** 2.5.3 (https://js.api.here.com/se/2.5.3/jsl.js?with=all) and created a `markersContainer` which contains a few `markers`.

After all markers are successfully added to the `markersContainer` i used `map.zoomTo(markersContainer.getBoundingBox(), false, "default");` to zoom to the markers bounds.

As we are using different map overlays the zoomLevel are not perfect to show all markers (they are behind an overlay at the top of the map). 
So we want to add some offset to the bounding box, such as the boundingBox is starting on the top of the map plus an offset of 180px.

So: Is there any `property` to use `zoomTo(boundingBox, false, "default")` within an `X/Y offset` to the `boundingBox` like:

Pseudo code:
`markersContainer.getBoundingBox(topleftOffset, bottomRightOffset)`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got it ... Using the [map.setPadding()](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.Display.html#topic-apiref__Display-setPadding)-Method.